# Count number of occurrence in the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I have a list like this:

```
res = [[('CARDINAL', 1)], [('CARDINAL', 4)], [('CARDINAL', 1), ('ORG', 1)],
       [('CARDINAL', 1)], [('ORG', 1)], [('OTHER', 1)], [('CARDINAL', 1)]]
```

how can I get output like

```
[{'CARDINAL' : 8, 'ORG' : 2, 'OTHER' : 1}]
```

Comment: Have you looked at ‘collections.Counter’?

Comment: What's with the weird nesting? Are those always lists of lists of tuples, or can it be different? Also, shouldn't it be `'CARDINAL': 8`?

Comment: yes, that will give you a count of similar tuples. But I want total count as I have mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

You can *flatten* your original list with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and then use *tallying* from [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter


res = [[('CARDINAL', 1)], [('CARDINAL', 4)], [('CARDINAL', 1), ('ORG', 1)],
       [('CARDINAL', 1)], [('ORG', 1)], [('OTHER', 1)], [('CARDINAL', 1)]]

out = Counter()
for k, v in chain.from_iterable(res):
    out[k] += v
print(out)  # Counter({'CARDINAL': 8, 'ORG': 2, 'OTHER': 1})
```

That being said, I have the impression that the solution to your problem might be better placed **before** you get to this nested list you have (`res`).

Comment: Why use `Counter` at all if you aren't using any of its features except for key initialization? A `defaultdict(int)` would be enough. A regular `dict` would do too, with `out[k] = out.get(k, 0) + v` instead of `out[k] += v` to initialize new keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the sequences of tuples to dicts first to construct `Counter` objects with the dicts so that you can take advantage of `Counter`'s key-based addition operation using the `sum` function:

```
from collections import Counter
sum(map(Counter, map(dict, res)), Counter())
```

which returns:

```
Counter({'CARDINAL': 8, 'ORG': 2, 'OTHER': 1})
```

Alternatively, use the `reduce` function with the `add` operator function to achieve the same result without having to initialize an empty `Counter` as a starting value:

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
reduce(add, map(Counter, map(dict, res)))
```